# Connection refused for netcat and other programs on localhost only

Tags: networking

I just discovered a problem with my Arch Linux installation which I think is pretty bizarre. To illustrate the problem I will use netcat, but this same thing seems to happen with a c program I wrote to test it out.

If I start a netcat listener like this:

```
netcat -l 5656
```

The process works as expected and netcat waits for something to connect to it. If I use the corresponding netcat command I get the following:

```
$ netcat -v localhost 5656
localhost [127.0.0.1] 5656: Connection refused
```

If I start a listener on another machine that I have SSH'd into I can netcat a message to it, but if the listener is on the Arch machine I always get a connection refused whether sending the message locally or remotely.

edit:

```
$ ifconfig lo
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 29243  bytes 2094780 (1.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 29243  bytes 2094780 (1.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0

$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

$ ip route show table local
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.8.0 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.7 
local 192.168.8.7 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.8.7 
broadcast 192.168.8.255 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.7 

# Static table lookup for hostnames.
# See hosts(5) for details.

$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost
127.0.1.1   arch.localdomain    arch
```

Comment: Can you verify that `netcat` is actually listening to `127.0.0.1:5656` on the `lo` interface and not on a specific _other_ interface (like `192.168.8.0:5656` on `wlp2s0`)?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes I can confirm. When netcat is listening it does not show up in the output of `lsof`.

Comment: The triple-replicated route already looks very wrong, so something else in your setup also needs fixing. But that shouldn't affect localhost. Next step is to look at the firewall (`iptables`). The step after that is to look at the policy routes (`ip rule`, `ip route show table local` etc.).

Comment: @dirkt I've listed the commands you suggested.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary so far. Next step is to look at `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`; 127.0.0.1 should be allowed (`ALL: 127.0.0.1`) or at least not denied by some other generic rule (like `ALL: ALL`).

Comment: @dirkt I don't have an "allow" or "deny" hosts file, but I've pasted my /etc/hosts file above.

Comment: `/etc/hosts` is a completely different thing, but if you have neither of those two files, that's also ok. Now I am running out of ideas where to look for the problem. If you try it with a different port, what happens? If you try a port below 1024 (`sudo` for the listener), what happens? If you try `socat` or `nc` instead (different commandline, read the man pages), what happens? But that's all clutching at straws...

Comment: I can reproduce the issue verbatim on debian testing without funny routes, or hosts

Answer (score 4):

Because there are different implementations out there. It seems that you may try this, running on debian 10:

server:

```
netcat -l -p 5656
```

client:

```
netcat -v 127.0.0.1 5656
Hello
World
<ctrl-C>
```

So it seems network is not the problem, even you have trippled the same route to default route in your table.

BTW `netcat` is realized as link to `nc`. So in debian in does not make a difference to use `nc` or `netcat`.

Comment: It was the `-p` that made a difference for me.  I could reproduce OPs issue until adding the `-p` you suggested to the server